# My app logs in twice with a URLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

When i press login in my app, it logs in twice in API instead of just once.., there is something wrong with this but i cant find what, because it just execute this code once.

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];     
    NSHTTPURLResponse   * response;
                NSError             * error;
                NSMutableURLRequest * request;
                NSString            * params;
                NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?action=request&api=json&module=ManagementModule&function=startSession&instance=0",[ConnectServer returnserverip]];
                NSLog(@"UPX %@",[ConnectServer returnserverip]);
                NSLog(@"IP %@",[ConnectServer returnclientip]);
                if([defaults boolForKey:@"enablePincode"]){
                    NSString *account = [defaults stringForKey:@"myAccount"];
                    NSString *username =[defaults stringForKey:@"myUsername"];
                    NSString *password = [defaults stringForKey:@"myPassword"];
                    NSString *clientip = [ConnectServer returnclientip];
                    NSString *clientname = [ConnectServer returnclientname];
                    params = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"params=&auth[password]=%@&auth[mode]=%@&auth[account]=%@&auth[user]=%@&auth[rights]=%@&auth[user_ip]=%@&auth[client_name]=%@",password,@"password",account,username,@"user",clientip,clientname] autorelease];
                }
                else {
                    NSString *clientip = [ConnectServer returnclientip];
                    NSString *clientname = [ConnectServer returnclientname];
                    params = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"params=&auth[password]=%@&auth[mode]=%@&auth[account]=%@&auth[user]=%@&auth[rights]=%@&auth[user_ip]=%@&auth[client_name]=%@",[myPassword text],@"password",[myAccount text],[myUsername text],@"user",clientip,clientname] autorelease];
                }
                request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60] autorelease];
                NSData *myRequestData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[[NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] host]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myRequestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
     NSLog(@"RESPONSE HEADERS: \n%@", [response allHeaderFields]);
    request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    error       = nil;
    response    = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"The server saw:\n%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]);
    NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", params);
    NSLog(@"Actual sended parameters to the server: %@", myRequestData);
    NSString *Sresponse;
    Sresponse = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: maybe your website processes the request and then sends accidently a redirect which is also performed by `NSURLConnection` which results in two HTTP-Post requests and your webserver also performs your action on the second request. This can be checked using wireshark or webserver-logs. (it's just an idea)

Comment: No,the problem isnt in the function that i call from the API, because if someone calls this function from someother way(website, windows program, etc..)it logs in once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two requests in the code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

and five lines down

```
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Hint: In cases like this use wireshark or my favorite Charles which will decode SSL connections.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is possible. I mean, I am running APEX at this very moment and I have the same app. running in 3 different windows under the same user without having to log on. The only time I have to log on is when I change user.
So yes, it is possible, but not sure why it is not working at your end. Could it be that you run both development and runtime at the same time using different users? Because if one of the APEX users differs from the other then you are prompted to log on again with the other user.